# determine the average difference between the events in days, within a column in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, date, average, window-functions

I am trying to determine the average difference between the events in days, within a column in mysql workbench.

sample data looks something like this :

[image]

I want to determine the average of duration between events grouped by organizer. any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you add your expected output with details?

Comment: what do you mean by average date??

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid output should be a 2X2 table, having organizer1 and organizer2 in column 1 and average difference between dates in column 2..

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `lag()` for this:

```
select avg(datediff(event_date, lag_event_date)) avg_diff
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lag(event_date) over(partition by nid order by event_date) lag_event_date
    from mytable t
) t
```

In earlier versions, a typical workaround is a correlated subquery:

```
select nid, avg(datediff(event_date, lag_event_date)) avg_diff
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        (
            select max(t1.event_date) 
            from mytable t1
            where t1.nid = t.nid and t1.event_date < t.event_date
        ) lag_event_date
    from mytable t
) t
group by nid
```

Comment: thanks .. but I am getting output as one value, but i want it group by nid. I am using sql 8.0

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to take the largest date minus the smallest date and divide by one less than the count:

```
select organizer,
       datediff(day, min(date), max(date)) * 1.0 / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0) as avg_day_diff
from t
group by organizer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
LAG([EVENT DATE],1) OVER ( ORDER BY [EVENT DATE]) AS PREV_EVENT_DATE,
DATEDIFF(DD, LAG([EVENT DATE],1) OVER ( ORDER BY [EVENT DATE]), [EVENT DATE]) AS DAYS_BETWEEN_EVENTS
```

`DAYS_BETWEEN_EVENT` Can then be used to calculate your average days difference.

The key piece of SQL to use in these instances is the `LAG` function because it allows you to return a value from the previous row. [Documentation here](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/lag.php)

Comment: thanks .. but this is giving me an error : 'incorrect parameter count in the call to native function DATEDIFF' :/